# child component without props re-renders even with react mem

Tags: reactjs

there are a lot of questions related to my issue, but all deal with child components with props. I am not sending any props but the child component is still getting re-rendered which is causing useless load on the db when the getstate function runs.

When i change the sidebar state in the parent, the child re-renders. What is causing the react memo to not work? and how to memoize the chart data to avoid hitting the db everytime the sidebar changes?

```js
 function Child() {
  const [state, setstate] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    getState('addressbalance');
  },[]);

  const getState = async (urlLoc) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(baseURL.concat(`/${urlLoc}`));
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      setstate(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  const renderChart = () => {
    return <ChartApex graph='Bar' data = {state} height={'95%'} width={'100%'}/>
  }

  return (
    <Explore>
      <Card  width="90%" height='550px'>
     {renderChart()}
      </Card>
    </Explore>
  );
}
export default React.memo(Child)
```

Parent

```js
<PageContainer changeSidebar={changeSidebar} sidebar={sidebar}>
 <Switch>
...
  <Route
   path="/addressbalance"
   component={() => <Child/>}
   />
  </Switch>
</PageContainer>
```

Comment: Is `AddressBalance`  and `Child` are same components?

Comment: yes my mistake, editing the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using setState in the memoized component, the documentation is explicit on this point :

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

> React.memo only checks for prop changes.
>
> If your function component wrapped in React.memo has a useState, useReducer or useContext Hook in its implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change.

Comment: Thank you, can you suggest a solution to the second question. "how to memoize the chart data to avoid hitting the db everytime the sidebar changes?"

Comment: Fetch the data at the PageContainer level and send it as prop to Child. Or use memo on the <ChartApex /> instance :)